# extract css data from web page using vba

Tags: css, vba, extract

With my code below the css data can be rewritten, but not be read.
How can I read the css-data?

I have been struggling with this problem for 2 days now. Any assistance would be truly appreciated.

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim divElem As HTMLDivElement
Sub GetCSSData()
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        IE.Navigate "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"
        IE.Visible = True
        While IE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

       Set divElem = IE.Document.getElementById("p-logo")
       ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = divElem.Style.Top  'Cell is empty
       divElem.Style.Top = "100px"
       ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value = divElem.Style.Top  'Cell get 100px
End Sub
```

Comment: Put a Watch on `divElem` (right-click > Add Watch) and a break at the line `ActiveSheet.Cells(...)` When the code hits the break, examine the members of `divElem` in the Watch window and you'll see a lot of potential properties you could use here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did it with 'divElem'. It has a lot of properties, but I did not find css-properties. And than I watched the 'divElem.Style'. It uncludes the css-properties, but all content is empty. I suppose that  css-properies can not be read with 'getElementById("..").Style'. Only write function is possible

Comment: What exactly were you after?